# Footnotes next to each other in a sideways table?

Tags: tables, footnotes, rotating

How can I put footnotes next to each other in a sideways table? The `para` option for `footmisc` does not work here.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % to rotate e.g. table
\usepackage[multiple,para]{footmisc} % separate footnotes by a comma

\usepackage{tablefootnote} % footnotes in tables

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[h]{| l |l  |l| } 
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \tablefootnote{Remark 1} \\
        \hline
        7 & 8 & 9 \tablefootnote{Remark 2} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 

    \caption{Caption} 
    \label{tab:natural}

\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example works without `tablefootnotes`, just use footnotes inside the sidewaystable. But I found no way to put the footnotes in one line, neither with bigfoot, manyfoot or eledmac.

Except that one of the wizards here provides a solution, there is a quick and dirty solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % to rotate e.g. table


%\usepackage{tablefootnote} % footnotes in tables

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[h]{| l |l  |l| } 
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \textsuperscript{a} \\
        \hline
        7 & 8 & 9 \textsuperscript{b} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\vspace{2ex}

\footnotesize \textsuperscript{a} Remark 1 \quad
  \textsuperscript{b} Remark 2
    \caption{Caption} 
    \label{tab:natural}

\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

One can refine this, by defining a counter, reseting it for the footnotes, and so on. But this is only worth the time and effort, if you have lots of footnotes in your sidewaystables.